# como hacer para que una persona suba imágenes en una aplicación hecha con app inventor?

Tags: app, appinventor

Aplicacion en app inventor
Como puedo hacer para que el usuario pueda subir imagenes a la aplicacion algo tipo instagram y lograr que las imagenes se muestren en otra ventana conforme las vaya subiendo

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Debes ser más especifico con lo que necesitas ayuda y mostrar un intento de lo que quieres hacer.